# Chrome seems to ignore 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' header

Tags: google-chrome, caching, cache-control

We are having an ongoing issue with a web application that we have developed where when we deploy a new version of the application, Chrome seems to ignore all the `Cache-Control` headers and load the application (index.html) out of disk cache, causing all kinds of errors for our users.

I've tried several different variations of the `Cache-Control` header, but it never seems to obey, including `Cache-Control: max-age: 0, must-revalidate` and `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

My questions are two-fold:  Is there something that I'm missing that might be causing this, and are there techniques that others are using to avoid this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct `max-age` syntax should be

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

You can also try

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

which basically cover all don't-cache directives, in case some proxy in between does not support newer syntax.